# PHP and variable in session

Tags: php, forms, session, session-variables, form-submit

I need to pass a variable between 2 php pages.

The second page is called from action in form after the submit of button.

> 

```
<body>
    <div>
        <form action="callSecondPage.php" method="POST">
            <div>
                <select name="taskOption">
                    <option>First</option>
                    <option>Second</option>
                    <option>Third</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <?php
                $currentValue = (isset($_POST['taskOption'])) ? $_POST['taskOption'] : '';
                $_SESSION['taskOption'] = $currentValue;
            ?>
            <div>
                <button name="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

in the second page i simply try to find the value and print it in console:

```
<?php   
  session_start();  
  $taskOption = $_SESSION['taskOption'];  
  echo '<script>';    
  echo 'console.log('. json_encode($taskOption, JSON_HEX_TAG) .')'; 
  echo '</script>';  ?>
```

Where am I wrong? Why is the value null in the second page?

Comment: is it to different files (`page1.php`, `page2.php`) and if so, do you do session_start() on the second?

Comment: This code is in first page true?  if yes you don't need to use `SESSION` instead you can use `POST` directly in `callSecondPage`

Comment: This code is in first page and yes there are 2 different files.

Comment: I tried to do POST directly is second page but the result is always the same... empty value.

Comment: <Option value='something'> is the syntax to pass value

Comment: @KenLee true but if `value` isn't set, the browser will simply send the text from inside the option tag instead, so that's unlikely to be the issue here.

Comment: `Why is the value null in the second page`...we don't know because you didn't show the code of the second page or explain what exactly was null. Please provide all the relevant info.

Comment: @ADyson in the second page i simply try to find the value and print it in console: 
`<?php 

session_start();

$taskOption= $_SESSION['taskOption'];

echo '<script>';
   echo 'console.log('. json_encode($taskOption, JSON_HEX_TAG) .')';
echo '</script>';

?>`

Comment: In future please edit your question when you need to add more code. Code in comments is hard to read as you can see for yourself. I added it for you this time, and then I've prepared an answer below - please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? If you post to the second script, there's no way the first one can store anything in the session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That makes no sense, because you've never stored the value in the session to begin with.  Your other code:

```
$currentValue = (isset($_POST['taskOption'])) ? $_POST['taskOption'] : ''; 
$_SESSION['taskOption'] = $currentValue;`
```

will always set an empty value in the Session, because the value it's trying to look for is posted directly to `callSecondPage.php`, it never passes through this code.

So because you're posting the value directly to the second page, in `callSecondPage.php` you could simply write

```
$taskOption= $_POST['taskOption'];
echo $taskOption;
```

to get it immediately from the POST data. No need for sessions.

Comment: Thanks, it working but i don't understand when you say that i'm setting the value in session directly in second page.
With this row: $_SESSION['taskOption'] = $currentValue;` in first page am i not setting the value in session?

Comment: `i don't understand when you say that i'm setting the value in session directly in second page`...neither do I, because I didn't say that. I said you're _posting the form_ directly to the second page. `action="callSecondPage.php"` means that as soon as you submit your form, the next code which runs is the code callSecondPage.php. It never goes back to your first page.

Comment: `With this row: $_SESSION['taskOption'] = $currentValue; in first page am i not setting the value in session`...you are setting a value, but it will always set the value to `""` (i.e. empty) - my answer already explains why. Please understand that `$_POST['taskOption']` will never exist in your first page, because you the form is submitted to the second page, not the first page.